# Show WhatsApp popup when clicking the message in notification panel

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, popup

We can enable popup notifications in WhatsApp settings for "Only when screen is on" and "Always show popup".

What I want is, it shouldn't show any popup when message arrives like popups are disabled, but when I click on the message in notification panel, it should show the popup and I can quickly reply.

Similar to what iOS "Quick Reply for WhatsApp" tweak does. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't use WhatsApp, so I'm a little confused. What happens now when you click the notification?

Comment: @DanHulme when clicking on notification, it takes the user to the conversation/thread in the app.

Comment: Ah, and Салман instead wants it to bring up the pop-up. I see. If there's no setting for that in the app, there's no way around it.

Comment: I see, I was thinking some app or tweak can bring up the popup when required.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109092/ios-quick-reply-feature-on-whatsapp-for-android (no answer yet as of now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WhatsApp has implemented this feature on Mar 29, 2016 (v2.12.560). As a fallback for [quick reply feature on Android N](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/04/15/android-n-dev-preview-2-expands-quick-reply-to-the-lockscreen/), WhatsApp added a (kind of) quick reply from notification for all Android version.

When a notification comes, you can expand it (i.e. by sliding down) to show the **Reply** button. Tapping the *Reply* button will bring the message as a popup, which you can also reply directly from there.

[image: new expanded notification] [image: message as popup]

<sup>Image courtesy of [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/03/30/whatsapp-adds-quick-reply-from-the-notification-multiple-contact-selection-solid-wallpaper-colors-and-finally-dumps-a-gingerbread-remnant/)</sup>