# iOS' Quick Reply feature on WhatsApp for Android

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, popup

Recently I got my first Android phone, LG G3 and updated to the Android Lollipop, the latest OS ver. The transition from iOS isn't smooth as I thought and this because I'm trying to find how to enable simplest features that came with iOS as default.

One of them is the option of receiving message in WhatsApp. In iOS, if the screen is locked and I get a message, I can see a preview of the message and by swiping, I can get to write back to the sender (whereas user or group). In Android, I just see i.e "50 messages from 3 conversations".

[image: WhatsApp quick reply]

<sup>"Slide to reply" on lock screen</sup>

I saw that I have the option in WhatsApp to "Always show pop up". Well, this brings any message from group (which I disabled) or users (which is enabled) with popup window and waiting that I'll type my response, I just want to see the little preview and if I want to respond I'll click on the specific message.

Is there any way (alternatively, 3rd-party apps) to have that feature? I have tried an app called [NiLS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roymam.android.notificationswidget) & [Notification Toggle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle&hl=en), but it doesn't feel like this is it.

Comment: You mean multiple notifications for each chat? I don't think WhatsApp for Android has that feature, even though it is easily possible.

Comment: Have you tried Flotify by Jawamo in Play Store?

Comment: @MANI i am trying Flotify, but i a getting double notifications one from the OS (lolipop) and the other from the app. Can i cancel the one from the OS without also disabling the one from the Flotify ?

Comment: Did you find any difference between system and Floatify notifications? Which one is better? Because I never used Lollipop.

Comment: Both feel the same. So I disabled flotify. Still looking for proper method for handling the notifications like the iOS.

Comment: @udi. You can also try CM Locker. Notifications will be shown on lock screen and swiping right on it will take you to the app.

Comment: For now i'll just use NILS which trying to immatate the iOS , but it is still doesnt fill as integral part of the system also i'm getting double notification from the OS and from NILs , without the option to disable the ones from the OS... :( seems that android lack this features among others that i miss with iOS

Comment: Try [CM Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cmcm.locker). This app enables the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Android N will have native quick reply feature (called [*Direct Reply*](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#notification_enhancements)), and while WhatsApp will probably use it, it won't work for pre-N (although it has implemented [its own quick reply from notification for all Android version](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61577/show-whatsapp-popup-when-clicking-the-message-in-notification-panel?lq=1)).

However, there are some apps that can emulate the direct reply feature on Android N:

- [quickReply](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamworks.quickreply) (free, 5.0+)

  > quickReply will show you separate notifications for every contact including reply action buttons, so you can easily write quick replies without opening the messaging app.
  >
  > **QUICKREPLY SUPPORTED APPS**:
  >   WhatsApp, Telegram, Threema, Skype, Line, WeChat, Kik, EvolveSms, YAATA, Textra, ChompSms, Hangouts, Handcent SMS...
- [Floatify - Quick Replies](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamworks.floatify) (free, 4.3+)

  > Advanced heads-Up notifications for your phone! QuickReply lets you send messages directly from the notification! ...
  >
  > **MAIN FEATURES**:
  >   Heads-up Quick Replies (5.0+, limited on 4.3+, see below for supported apps)
  >
  > **QUICKREPLY REPORTED WORKING**:
  >   WhatsApp, Telegram, Threema, Skype, Line, WeChat, Kik, EvolveSms, YAATA, Textra, ChompSms, Hangouts, Handcent SMS...

<sup>Both apps are developed by Jawomo, so it's not really surprising they have similar feature and supported apps...</sup>